# Center orange dot

Tags: selection-tools

How can I center the orange dot so that it is in the middle of the object/that the move tool is in the middle of the object?
Thank you.

[image: orange dot bottom right]
[image: move tool]

Comment: object -> set origin -> geometry

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome